# StackPanel orientation horizontal start from right to left in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, xamarin.uwp

i wanna make multi language wpf app like arabic and englich
so i built it change the text to arabic and to englich but the layout still staring from left to right
i want to flip it when i change the language and i dont have any keyword to start searching
and i think i will be just flip the stackpanel so can any one help me

```
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

 <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name  :  " HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#31383F"></TextBlock>
                               
 <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name  :  " HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#31383F"></TextBlock>
                               
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```